# Stuck with C syntax

Tags: c, syntax, pointers

I am trying to remove spaces from the end of a char array (string).

This is the pseudo code of what I am doing, but it keeps deleting the whole string:

```
if(string length - 1 != a space)
    return
```

Otherwise, it must equal a space, so

```
while *mypointer-- != a space
//This should loop back to where there is a character.
```

Outside of the while loop, I now add one to the pointer by doing

```
mypointer ++;
```

and then set mypointer '\0' to signal the end of the string.

I am doing something fundamentally wrong inside of my while, but I cannot seem to figure it out. What could it be?

Comment: why not post the C code you have written?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little clairvoyance:

```
while(*mypointer == a space) {
    --mypointer;
}
mypointer[1] = '\0';
```

Notice that it is == a space not != a space.

---

Edit:
If I were going to write this, I'd probably really use something like:

```
#include <string.h>
...

char *mypointer = strrchr(string, ' ');
if (mypointer) *mypointer = '\0';
```

Comment: You'll want to write the `\0` one byte further, you're overwriting the last non-space character now.

Comment: don't forget that Very Bad Things may happen if your string is all spaces.

Comment: also char * mpointer = s + strlen(s); and I would put in ' ' not 'a space' just so its clear u dont mean " "

Comment: and i was just going to say what plinth said

Comment: Richard, `strrchr` will find the last space: consider the strings `"this is a test"`, and `"this   "`.  The second string has more than one space at the end, somehow SO is not showing it.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably setting `mypointer` to `\0`, which sets the pointer to `NULL`.  You need to set `mypointer[1]` to `\0`.  Also, make sure you do the right thing for the following edge-cases:

- when a string is all spaces,
- when string length is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Without the code we can just guess:

How is `mypointer` initialized?

Are you sure about the while loop condition? Should it be while 'last character is space'?

Answer (score 0):

A slight improvement perhaps:

```
while(*mypointer == a space) {
  *mypointer-- = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [code](http://c.snippets.org/snip_lister.php?fname=notrail.c) that does the exact job to strip spaces from the end of the string...this is from the Snippets archive - it's an educational thing to watch what's going on when stepping through the debugger and very useful collection of C code also...